# Combine multiple .pptx files into one file in R

Tags: r, powerpoint, presentation

I'd like to combine all powerpoint files into one file using R:

```
> list.files("/src/dev/export_performance/slides/")
 [1] "slide-1.pptx"  "slide-11.pptx" "slide-12.pptx" "slide-13.pptx" "slide-14.pptx" "slide-15.pptx" "slide-2.pptx" 
 [8] "slide-3.pptx"  "slide-4.pptx"  "slide-5.pptx"  "slide-6.pptx"  "slide-7.pptx"  "slide-8.pptx"  "slide-9.pptx"
```

Is there any tool to do it?

Comment: Have a look at [officer](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer)... but unless this is a task you are doing regularly, it may not be worth the setup just to combine. Do you have the option to `pdf` the individual slides? you could then just use ghostscript to stitch them together.

Comment: No, it must be powerpoint. And `officer` package doesn't have option to merge two `.pptx` files.